# NA в цикле for при числах более 9

Tags: r, rstudio

при попытке создать цикл с индексацией и расчитать сумму текущего элемента и следующего выдается часть значений в виде NA, при этом NA становятся только значения которые должны быть больше 9

```
a <- c(10, 20, 70, 40, 5)
   for (i in a){
    print(i+a[i+1])
   }
```

[image: на выходе этого цикла получаются такие значения]

Answer (score 2):

`i in a` - это 10, 20, 70, 40, 5.
`a[i+1]` - это `a[10+1]`, `a[20+1]` и т.д. Но в `а` нет элементов под номером 11, 21... Там всего 5 элементов.

Comment: а как правильно индексировать вектора при написании циклов?

Comment: Вместо `i in a` надо писать `i in seq_len(length(a))`

Comment: на всякий случай на будущее спрошу, где я могу найти информацию о индексации в циклах for и while? Пытался искать информацию или примеры, но результаты были нулевые

Comment: Примеры есть в Matloff N. Art of R Programming. A Tour of Statistical Software Design. Там же написано про то, как без циклов обходиться по возможности.

Comment: И еще лучше писать даже не `seq_len(length(a))`, а `seq_along(a)`