# NaNs produced R/RStudio

Tags: r, rstudio

```
x<-c(1:20)

y<-c(1:20)

z<-c(1:20)

for(i in x){

  z[i]<-sqrt((x[i]^2)/25-3*(y[i]^2))

}
```

Заполняет массив z[] NaNами. В чем проблема?

Comment: собственно, дубликат: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1086276/178576

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [NA в цикле for при числах более 9](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1086276/na-%d0%b2-%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b5-for-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%85-%d0%b1%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b5-9)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Причина ошибки - отрицательное число как аргумент функции `sqrt`.

Comment: Эй, вы чего? Это правильный ответ.